# dataProvider Pagination without CGridView

Tags: php, yii

How to show the pagination in the view, with own design, using `dataProvider`?
Im not using `CGridView` to show `dataProvider` items.

Controller.php:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Projects', array(
        'criteria'=>array(
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>Yii::app()->params['itemsPerPage'],
        ),
    ));

    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the CGridView, CListView and .. use a widget called, CLinkPager

[Check here for more info](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager)

It also gives good example in the comments about using it in controller and comment. I'm sure you can easily adopt your dataprovider to CLinkPager. Good luck. Read the public properties, you can even use your own CSS, for different pages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`ClinkPager`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CLinkPager) or [`CListPager`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListPager) render a pager. Below is an example using `CLinkPager`

```
$this->widget('ClinkPager',array('pages'=>new CPagination(100)));
```